# Can we change real time database in our app while the app is in review mode?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-play-console

We have listed our android app on the play store to get published but it is up for review for 3-6 business days. So in the meantime, can we update the real-time database of firebase? Will it affect our review time?

Like if I make changes in the database, the data in the app will also change, so will google start the review process again?

Please tell. It is important.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the data. Just make sure not to break the App. If it has errors because of that it can get denied. Othervise it should not be any problem.